# How to get all distinct id from two tables after join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get all distinct value from two tables after join. Tow tables are..
Table: Student

```
Roll    Name
1       Anis
2       Badol
3       Chaity
```

Table:Exam

```
Roll    Quiz    Mid Final
1        15     20  40
3        25     20  42
4        10     12  8
```

I want to get that output

```
Roll    Name    Mark
3      Chaity   87
1       Anis    75
4      Unknown  30
2      Badol    0
```

where name in null that replaced by 'Unknoun' and mark is null that replaced by '0'

I tried this code

```
select s.roll, name, (quiz+mid+final) as Mark
from student s
full outer join exam e on
s.roll=e.roll
```

and get that output..

```
roll   name    mark
1      anis     75
2      badol    NULL
3     chaity    87
NULL    NULL    30
```

(sorry for the bad English)

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `full outer join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(t1.roll, t2.roll) as roll,
       coalesce(t1.name, 'Unknown') as name,
       (coalesce(quiz, 0) + coalesce(mid, 0) + coalesce(final, 0)) as mark
from t1 full outer join
     t2
     on t1.roll = t2.roll
order by mark desc;
```